# Kotlin - Programmatically created Spinner arrow missing

Tags: android, kotlin, android-spinner, android-dialog

After creating a `Spinner` programmatically, the dropdown arrow normally positioned to the right is not appearing for some reason. Why has the arrow gone and how can that be shown?

```
        spinnerItems = arrayOf(
            "Cathedral of the Intercession of the Most Holy Theotokos on the Moat",
            "Ferapontov Monastery",
            "Historic Monuments of Novgorod and Surroundings",
            "Golden Mountains of Altai",
            "Historic Centre of Saint Petersburg and Related Groups of Monuments",
            "Bogoroditse-Smolensky Monastery",
            "White Monuments of Vladimir and Suzdal"
        )

        val mySpinner =
            Spinner(view!!.context, null, android.R.style.Widget_Material_Spinner, Spinner.MODE_DROPDOWN)

        val arrayAdapter = ArrayAdapter(view!!.context, android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, spinnerItems)
        arrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line)

        mySpinner.adapter = arrayAdapter

        mFrameLayout.addView(mySpinner)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's because of style you choose for your spinner

```
android.R.style.Widget_Material_Spinner
```

unlike default behavior arrow isn't included in this style. you need to replace it with another style or add arrow by yourself.

```
val mySpinner = Spinner(
        ContextThemeWrapper(this, R.style.Widget_AppCompat_Spinner_Underlined),
        null,
        0,
        Spinner.MODE_DROPDOWN
    )
```

try this

Comment: Which style has the arrow by default?

Comment: just dont state style at all val mySpinner = Spinner(this, Spinner.MODE_DROPDOWN), just this would do the trick

Comment: That solved it. Do you know how to use the underline style like [this one](http://i.stack.imgur.com/T1lIj.png)? In XML I used to use `style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Spinner.Underlined"` but can this be done programmatically at all?

Comment: Great but now this has caused other problems, which I can't find similar tickets for. I've asked about this in a [new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61409715/kotlin-programmatically-created-spinner-dropdown-shows-underline-and-arrow-in?noredirect=1#comment108636176_61409715).

Comment: I saw your post I have been trying to do something about it but it just getting weirder I guess something wrong with spinner api? anyways I have some ideas and if I managed to fix it I will reach to you!