# Kotlin - Programmatically created Spinner dropdown shows underline and arrow in dropdown

Tags: android, kotlin, android-spinner

Why do I get this weird dropdown behaviour whenever I use a custom text view for my `Spinner`? The dropdown seems to be obtaining the underline and arrow drawable for some reason, which I never asked for. How can this be removed?

**Fragment**

```
        spinnerItems = arrayOf(
            "Cathedral of the Intercession of the Most Holy Theotokos on the Moat",
            "Ferapontov Monastery",
            "Historic Monuments of Novgorod and Surroundings",
            "Golden Mountains of Altai",
            "Historic Centre of Saint Petersburg and Related Groups of Monuments",
            "Bogoroditse-Smolensky Monastery",
            "White Monuments of Vladimir and Suzdal"
        )

        val mySpinner = Spinner(ContextThemeWrapper(view!!.context, R.style.Widget_AppCompat_Spinner_Underlined),
            null,
            0,
            Spinner.MODE_DROPDOWN
        )

        val arrayAdapter = ArrayAdapter(view!!.context, R.layout.tv_spinner_item, spinnerItems)
        arrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.tv_spinner_item)

        mySpinner.adapter = arrayAdapter

        mFrameLayout.addView(mySpinner)
```

**custom dropdown item**

```
<TextView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        style="?android:attr/dropDownItemStyle"
        android:id="@+id/my_spinner_item"
        android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true" />
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Could you add the `tv_spinner_item` and `my_spinner_item ` layout files to the question?

Answer (score 0):

okay I managed to find out pretty cheap solution but it seems to work. just put your spinner creation logic in xml, say like that :

```
<Spinner 
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Spinner.Underlined"
     android:id="@+id/mySpinner"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

and then inflate it in your layout from code, you would do it from activity like that :

```
    layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.item, frameLayout)

    val arrayAdapter = ArrayAdapter(this, R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item, spinnerItems)
    arrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item)

    mySpinner.adapter = arrayAdapter
```

Comment: Cool, but now I can't click any of the items. I've asked [a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61418122/android-spinner-custom-text-view-not-clickable)