# Android Spinner custom text view not clickable

Tags: android, kotlin, android-spinner

Why does using a custom text view prevent the Spinner text & items (yet not the arrow) from being clickable and yet this isn't the case with Android-prvoided Spinner text layouts?

**works when used**

```
    val arrayAdapter = ArrayAdapter(view!!.context, android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, spinnerItems)
    arrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line)
```

**XML**

```
<Spinner
        android:id="@+id/mySpinner"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Spinner.Underlined"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:spinnerMode="dialog"/>
```

**Kotlin**

```
    spinnerItems = arrayOf(
        "Cathedral of the Intercession of the Most Holy Theotokos on the Moat",
        "Ferapontov Monastery",
        "Historic Monuments of Novgorod and Surroundings",
        "Golden Mountains of Altai",
        "Historic Centre of Saint Petersburg and Related Groups of Monuments",
        "Bogoroditse-Smolensky Monastery",
        "White Monuments of Vladimir and Suzdal"
    )

    val arrayAdapter = ArrayAdapter(view!!.context, R.layout.spinner_item, spinnerItems)
    arrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.spinner_item)

    mSpinner.adapter = arrayAdapter
```

**spinner_item.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        style="?android:attr/dropDownItemStyle"
        android:id="@+id/my_SpinnerItem"
        android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:paddingBottom="16dp"
        android:paddingTop="16dp"
        android:textColor="?android:attr/textColorPrimary" />
```

Comment: Use the same `id` as it is in the default android `XML`

Comment: @OhhhThatVarun Can you be s bit more specific please? `id` of what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove these two lines:

```
android:clickable="true"
android:focusable="true"
```

Your code works fine.